# Could anyone tell me the meaning of 'celebration number 103'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

Can anyone tell me the meaning of 'celebration number 103'?
This is the text that I was reading in journal.

> Until December 28, that is, when, as I set out towards 'celebration number 103' of the Christmas season, I noticed a rather serious-looking letter addressed to me lying on the hall rug.

I think the author was planning going out (set out?) to celebrate something because it was the Christmas season. But I have no idea what the number 103 means.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the author was simply exaggerating the number of celebrations he or she had to attend during the Christmas season.  Using "celebration 103" is meant to be rather humorous in communicating this.

Comment: Now, I can see the meaning of sentence clearly. Thank you very much!